# onclick on anchor gets triggered only when clicking at edge on mobile devices

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement a simple anchor which calls a javascript function on click . The font of the text used is a bit big . It works as expected on normal browsers. The js gets triggered wherever I click on the text. But on a mobile device, it seems the js gets triggered only when clicking the top edge of the text and does not get triggered anywhere else on the anchor.

I did try adding width and height, without success

```
<a class="" href="" onclick="alert('i am here');" style="
        cursor: crosshair;
        font-size:25px;">
    Hello 

</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
<a class="" href="" onclick="alert('i am here');" style="
        cursor: crosshair;
        font-size:25px;
        display: inline-block;
        line-height: 28px">
    Hello 
</a>
```

By the way, what is mobile device and browser?

Comment: browser is just normal chrome browser, mobile is when change the user agent in chrome to simulate a mobile device display.

Comment: Do you have any other elements and the its styles? Maybe there are conflicts. Something is closing on them.

Comment: This does not seems to work too. The click gets registered only at the top edge of the link. 

This is what I am exactly trying to do. The snippet seems to work only when I click on the edge of the anchor's area.
If I try this on the chrome browser, it works fine. But changing the user agent to simulate a mobile, it just does not work properly

Comment: .nav-link {
    color: #ffffff !important;
    float: left;
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: -3px;
    width: 44px;
    height: 44px;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
}
<a ng-show="true" class="nav-link" href="#/ProgramAgreement" data-ng-click="click($event)">&nbsp;</a>